# Declare a "type" object globally

Tags: vba, object, global-variables

I want to pass objects between form modules.

I have made a simple database to explain the problem I am having.
I have two forms --> form1, form2 and one module --> Module1
Based on the threads I have read, I believe if I want to define a global object, it should be done in the module so I placed the declaration there;

```
Option Compare Database

Public Type Name
    First As String
    Last As String
    Phone As String
End Type
```

On form1 I have a cmd button with the following code behind it;

```
Option Compare Database

Dim My_Name As Name

Private Sub cmd_Button_Click()
My_Name.First = "MyFirstName"
My_Name.Last = "MyLastName"
MsgBox ("In Form1 " & My_Name.Last)

DoCmd.OpenForm "Form2"
End Sub
```

on the second form I have;

```
Option Compare Database
Dim my_Name As Name
Private Sub Form_Load()
MsgBox (my_Name.First)
End Sub
```

In the first form, I see the my_Name object variable fine, when I pass control to the second form, I lose the variable.

I have tried a number of variations of Public, Static declarations all over the place on both the object variable and the sub's but I cannot figure out how to preserve the object across modules.

Comment: Use `Option Explicit`, for this and many other reasons. every time you use it you will prevent 10 bugs from entering your code.

Answer (score 0):

You are re-declaring my_name.  So it is in -effect two different things.  Like george forman and george forman.

I am sorry I can't be more help it's been like a a million years since I have had to deal with this.  However, it seems that your 'froms' are actually declared in an 'module' like block -name from1.  That from global scope you can reference a variable in your form1.

In this case form1.my_name.  However, this can lead to issues if form1.my_name has not yet been instanciated.

My recommendation is to find the module with global scope ( I dont remember exactly what it is, if you have to create it or now, and when it gets life).  Declare and initicialize your variables in it. Then access those from within you event handlers ("cmd_Button_Click" for example.)

Comment: Thanks, but if I don't declare it again, I get an error when the second form opens "Run-time error '424' , object required.

Comment: 'Dim my_Name As Name' both of those are declairations.  where ever you are putting 'Public Type Name' put 'public my_Name As Name'.  Whatever the name of the module is that you declare the type, becomes part of the name of the variable (module1.my_name).

Comment: Terary, Thanks, I figured there must be a global scope module but my search, to this point, came up empty. Ill keep banging away. Thanks for the feedback.  I'll keep plugging away.

Comment: Are you use using access?  What version?

Comment: You nailed it.  That works! Thanks.  Can teach an old dog new tricks.  Thanks Terary.